# Invalid hook call when using React Swiper and NextJS together

Tags: next.js, swiper.js

I am trying to use swiper with NextJS but the simplest example is causing Invalid hook call. I tried to downgrade the swiper version to 7 but that didn't worked.

Here is my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "next-sanity": "^0.5.2",
    "next-sanity-extra": "^0.2.3",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "sanity-react-extra": "^0.2.4",
    "swiper": "^8.2.4",
    "zustand": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.38",
    "@types/react": "18.0.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "4.7.2"
  }
```

Here is the swiper component

```
import React from "react";
import { HomHeroProps } from "@lib/@types/home.types";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

export const Hero: React.FC<HomHeroProps> = ({ carousel, description }) => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily fixed it by downgrading to react 17